# gcc-fortran missing component libmpfr

Tags: linux, gcc, fortran, gfortran, archlinux

I have installed gcc-fortran on arch linux

When try to compile a hello world program with `gfortran helloWorld.f90`, where this file is just

```
 Program Hello
      Print *, "Hello World!"
      End Program Hello
```

I get:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.1/f951: error while loading shared libraries: libmpfr.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Is this a missing component of gcc? I guess libmpfr is somehow missing? I see gcc-libs is installed.

Comment: It does not appear as a dependency for `gcc-fortran`, which is weird. Can you try to install `mpfr` and check?

Comment: Sorry, it does appear as a dependency of `libmpc` that is in `gcc-libs`. Can you try to request the update anyway?

Comment: You can download the library here: ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure and install manually by typing "tar xjf mpfr-3.1.4.tar.bz2" and copying the files into that folder it lists.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a missing component of gcc?

[GCC requires](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html) a few host libraries that are not hosted with GCC.  The problem is usually that these libraries were not added before configuring GCC by running [`./contrib/download_prerequisites`](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=contrib/download_prerequisites;hb=HEAD).

This script will download the appropriate versions of GMP, MPC, MPFR into the GCC source tree and perform in-tree builds of them before building the compiler proper, and it will also trigger installing these host libs with a GCC install.

However, if you configure with `--with-mpfr=` etc. after installing MPFR, then that lib is present on the **build** machine but not necessarily on the **host** machine, i.e. the machine that is supposed to run the compiler to be built.  Hence, when using `--with-mpfr=`, `--with-gmp=` and the like extra care must be taken to make sure that these dependencies will have been resolved before running the compiler.